# Using GsonBuilder.setdateformat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") can I convert a date json Object to key value pair?

Tags: java, gson, simpledateformat

Currently I am using Gson to convert an object to json
Custom Adapter

```java
public class MyDataMsgSerializer implements JsonSerializer<MyDataMsg>, JsonDeserializer<MyDataMsg>{
    
    private static Gson gson;
    static {
        try {
            gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(BsCal.class, new CalendarSerializer()).setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").serializeNulls().create();        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
    }
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(MyDataMsgsrc, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonElement jsonSubscription = gson.toJsonTree(src, typeOfSrc);
        return jsonSubscription;
    }
    @Override
    public MyDataMsg deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        return gson.fromJson(json, MyDataMsg.class);
    }

}
```

```java
private String convertObjToJson(MyDataMsg myDataMsg) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(BsCal.class, new CalendarSerializer()).setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(MyDataMsg.class, new MyDataMsgSerializer()).serializeNulls()
                .create();
        String jsonToString = gson.toJson(myDataMsg);
        LOGGER.info("Converted Json Object {}", jsonToString);
        return jsonToString;
    }
```

output:

```json
"myDataMsg": {
    "emplId": "15163",
    "mnthCd": "202211",
    "empltype": "M",
    "workingCd": "wfh",
    "btchnm": "0499",
    "shift": "1",
    "shiftStTm": {
      "dateTime": "2022-11-30 00:00:00”,
      "timeInMs": 1669766400000
    },
    "actncd": "UPDATE",
    "IsLead": null,
    "nightSf": "2",
    "overtm": null,
    "totalOverTm": null,
    "ExtraSal": "630"
}
```

Currently the 'shiftStTm' is being generated as below

```
"shiftStTm": {
      "dateTime": "2022-11-30 00:00:00",
      "timeInMs": 1669766400000
    },
```

I want it to be generated as this (key value)

```json
"shiftStTm":"2022-11-30 00:00:00"
```

could any one help me here to format it to key value using GsonBuilder??

I am using GsonBuilder to convert MyDataMsg to json In which the date is formatting as object instead of key vale, could you please help me to fix the issue?

Comment: In general you probably also need to write a custom type adapter for the type of the `shiftStTm` field. Though could you please include the code for `MyDataMsg` and `MyDataMsgSerializer` (and any of your classes they refer to); you can reduce them to only the code necessary to reproduce this issue. Without that code it is difficult to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: @Marcono1234 please find the custom Adapter in the question

Comment: Just to make sure there is no misunderstanding, the `MyDataMsgSerializer` exists to only customize serialization of `BsCal` within `MyDataMsg`, right? Though that seems to be redundant if you set that custom serializer also globally in `convertObjToJson` as well. Also, as mentioned earlier please also include the code for `MyDataMsg` (and probably `BsCal` too), ideally reduced to what is necessary to reproduce this issue. (see [minimal reproducible example guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))